# Communicating offline between different android devices

Tags: applications, wifi-hotspot, offline, data-transfer, web-server

I have multiple android devices that need to operate in areas with limited network connectivity. At the same there, I need the data capture on one of them to be immediately available on another device in the vicinity. The different devices can connect to one host device which can host the wi-fi and hence be in the same LAN. Then, what are some good ways to use the host device as a server that can persist and expose data?

Comment: What kind of data do you want to capture? You can run a server locally very easily on Android.  I use [Servers Ultimate Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimatepro) but take a look at the lists [here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server) compiled by user *Izzy*.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple actually. With "ssh server" (ice cold apps is a good one), you can install it on each android device, and then connect from one device to another across your Lan. Of course if you have no network connectivity you won't be able access the Web, but it should be possible to push pull data using rsync (you will need busy box and root to gain full functionality), but it is certainly very possible.

Although, depending on what you actually want to achieve, some easier options are available - eg for simple file sync, you can use bittorrent sync, even without an Internet connection

Comment: You can in fact use SFTP to copy to-and -from the device. SFTP can be mounted as a drive/folder on both Windows/Linux easily.